# Iframe data loading issue

Tags: javascript, angular, performance

I have a web application that uses multiple iframes to load data from different URLs(loading reports from different BI tools). When I click for example on 2nd iframe, the data of 1st iframe is loaded in 2nd iframe for a while and then the 2nd iframe's data gets loaded. How to remove this 1st iframe data from loading into 2nd?

Comment: If its angular 1.x version use `angularjs` tag else use `angular` tag. And maybe some code would be helpful although your problem is perfectly understandable ^^ I'm just wondering how do you know about the loading thing, can you see it?

Comment: Hi Costa thanks for reverting. I am using angular 12.1.2.suppose I have two iframes one showing pie chart data from website abc and other showing bar graph from website xyz. So when I click on 1st iframe it shows me pie chart from website abc but when I close this iframe and open 2nd one, it shows me content of 1st iframe for few seconds (i.e pie chart from website abc) and then shows actual data(i.e. graph from website xyz). How to prevent this fractional content from 1st iframe appearing in second?

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. Just used ngIf wer iframe was present in the code that will check if reports were present then oly display the data and gave one cleanup method in close button that would empty all the report data upon closing.